# ocaml debugger can't find core when run from emacs

Tags: debugging, emacs, ocaml

I'm trying to use the ocaml debugger to display variables at runtime from emacs. When I use the middle mouse button, as suggested by [this guide](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual030.html#toc132) my system just pastes from the clipboard. When I try to explicitly use the display command on a variable, I get

```
Cannot find module Core.Std
```

I have no problems with this when I compile using corebuild, so I know I have Core installed. Also, when I explicitly use the directory command to add the libraries for core and core_extended, it properly displays the variable. Is there some better way to make this work?

Comment: How did you install Core?  Via OPAM?  Are the OCaml environment variables available in your Emacs?

Comment: Yes I did install via opam. And what do you mean by the ocaml environment variables? I have my config set up so that I can use tuareg, merlin, ocp-indent, etc.

Comment: `CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH` must be available in `process-environment` to make OPAM libraries available to ocaml when running from Emacs.

Comment: within process-environment, OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH=$HOME/.opam/4.01.0/lib/toplevel, and CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.opam/4.01.0/lib/stublibs. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 3):

To print values `ocamldebug` needs to have the `.cmi` file containing the value's type in its search path. You can add directories to the search path using `-I` command-line arguments or the `directory` command.

Whilst `ocamlfind` doesn't seem to support `ocamldebug` directly, you can still use it to pass the correct `-I` arguments using the following command-line:

```
ocamldebug `ocamlfind query -recursive -i-format core` foo
```

where `foo` is the program being debugged.

Comment: if the fix is so simple, then why isn't it added already to ocamlfind.